# Java persistence - creating query faiils

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I am trying to write my first JPA web application and I am stuck. I have the following code:

```
@Stateless
public class TestDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="dbcon")    
    EntityManager em;

    public TestDAO() {

    }

    public TestCon getData() {
        Query qry = em.createQuery("select t from TestCon t");
        ...
```

the last line fails - " java.lang.NullPointerException". The TestCon code is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "testcon", schema = "C##test")
public class TestCon {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "a")
    private int a;

    @Column(name = "b", length = 20)
    private String b;

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

And the persistence.xml code as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="dbcon" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/OracleDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>code.TestCon</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
        </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Spring for dependency injection?  Your code never sets up an EntityManager...

Comment: No, not using Spring. The entitymanager is not created from a factory. It is injected as a resource from the container through the @PersistenceContext(unitName="dbcon")

Comment: as you can clearly see, it is not...

Comment: I can not get it, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The `@PersistenceContext` annotation will only work in a Java EE container. Which app server are you running?

If you're not running a Java EE container but just a servlet container like Tomcat, you need to create an `EntityManager` using `EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()`.

Comment: I am using the JBOSS server. And I tried with EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() and it didn't work

Comment: Where is your `persistence.xml` located at runtime?

Comment: You end up with a `src` directory at runtime? I don't think you should. How do you package and deploy your war/ear?